# Redirecting URL with (Brackets)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

does anyone know how I can redirect a URL with brackets? I made a mistake a while back and we have since changed to a proper url format but the link with URL remains indexed in Google.

I've tried the following but none seems to be working

```
RewriteRule ^url-with-(brackets)(.*)$ http://url.com/url-with-no-brackets$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^url-with- \brackets\ (.*)$ http://url.com/url-with-no-brackets$1 [R=301]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being precise - that would be the rounded brackets () not the curly

Comment: OK so that's not a bracket those are called parenthesis :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting me ... LOL, we call it brackets here. Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\((.+)\)(.*)$ /$1$2$3 [R=301,L]
```

This will extract the entire text without the parenthesis.

**Keep in mind that you may have been cached from previous attempts since you are using `301` so I recommend you that you test it using a different browser just to make sure its working.**

Comment: Thanks Prix that fixes it. Really appreciate it.